# how to play YouTube video url´s in MPMoviePlayerController without using YouTube iOS library in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to play YouTube video url´s or video id in `MPMoviePlayerController` without using YouTube iOS library in Objective-C

Comment: https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit

Comment: But this is not detail documentation also this is not work for me! is there any other solution??

Comment: You need to know the videoId of all the videos you want to play from youtube. Without that it is difficult use any other library. The above depends on you to get the videoId from the youtube and then pass that videoId to play the videos.

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh,
You can play youtube in webview

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoKey";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: what is video key? also i dont want to use you tube player instead that any player is ok.simply want to play you tube url in MPmovieplayer.

Comment: its your you tube video id